# Scrapy: making loop to add one item to other values

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm using scrapy for scraping some pages and I want in each row:

- Title
- Url
- Author

The problem is that (sometimes) there are more titles and urls but the author comes just one time in each page. So I want to add the respective author to urls and titles (which come out fine).

This is my (bad) code, I tried to make a loop but it doesn't work very well I think, plus, it raises me the error "Spider must return Request, BaseItem, dict or None, got 'list'". Can you tell me where is my mistake?

```
def parse(self, response):
    sels = response.xpath('//td[@class="default"]')
    items = []

    for sel in sels:
        item = ThisItem()
        item['URL'] = sel.xpath('//td[@class]/a/@href').extract()
        item['TITLE'] = sel.xpath('//td[@class]/a').extract()

    i = item['TITLE']

    for i in sels:
        item['AUTHOR'] = sel.xpath('//td[@class]/b[1]').extract()

    items.append(item)

    yield items
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should `yield` every `item` separately. Try this

```
def parse(self, response):
    author = response.xpath('//td[@class]/b[1]').extract()
    for sel in response.xpath('//td[@class="default"]'):
        item = ThisItem()
        item['URL'] = sel.xpath('//td[@class]/a/@href').extract()
        item['TITLE'] = sel.xpath('//td[@class]/a').extract()
        item['AUTHOR'] = author
        yield item
```

Comment: Already done: it gives me something like:

Title - Url - Author;
Tilte - Url - Blank;
Title - Url - Blank;
Title - Url - Author

Ecc.

Comment: let me see the html page example

Comment: I fixed the answer, check again. If author comes just one time, you should use `response` object for extraction, instead of `sel`